# How to rename a NiFi Controller Service?

Tags: apache-nifi

In Nifi, When defining multiple controller services of the same type, it is getting clumsy. Also as verified under "*Edit*" option of the *Controller Service*, I don't see an option. How to rename a controller service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you edit the controller service, there is a Settings tab with a Name property, which you can edit to rename the Controller Service:

[image]

Comment: The service also need to be disabled.